# Calculating the similarity of multiple elements with unequal length of a nested list

Tags: python, list, similarity

I have a nested list, with every second element having varying lengths:

```
lst = [[a,bcbcbcbcbc],[e,bbccbbccb],[i,ccbbccbb],[o,cbbccbb]]
```

My output is a csv of dataframe with this look:

```
comparison     similarity_score
   a:e          *some score      
   a:i          *some score
   a:o          *some score
   e:i          *some score
   e:o          *some score
   i:o          *some score
```

my code:

```
similarity = []
for i in lst:
    name = i[0]
    string = i[1]
    score = 0.0
    length =(len(string))
    for i in range(length):
        if string[i]==string[i+1]:
            score += 1.0
    new_score = (100.0*score)/length
    name_seq = name[i] + ':' + name[i+1]
    similarity.append(name_seq,new_score)

similarity.pdDataFrame(similarity, columns = ['comparison' , 'similarity_score'])
similarity.to_csv('similarity_score.csv')
```

but I am recieving an error:

```
    if codes[i]==codes[i+1]:
          IndexError: string index out of range
```

any advice? thanks!

Comment: Where is numPlaces initialized? codes[i]==codes[i+1] doesn't appear in your code snippet, unless you mean string[i]==string[i+1]

Comment: What is `numPlaces` (perhaps it's supposed to be `length`)? And why does the line in your exception not match any of the lines in the code you've shown? Anyway, I think you're getting confused about `i` because you're using the same variable name for two different things at different times. And if `name` is `a` in your list, the place you're doing `name[i+1]` doesn't many any sense at all.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks you for the corrections. I have to admit I am quite confused with the i's in the for loops.

Answer (score 1):

According to Python's documentation `range` does the following by example:

> >>>range(10)
>   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In your code (assuming variable names have not changed):

```
...
length =(len(string))            # For an input of 'bcb' length will be 3
for i in range(length):          # For an input of 'bcb' range will be [0, 1, 2]
    if string[i]==string[i+1]:   # When i == 2 i + 1 == 3 which gives you the
                                 # IndexError: string index out of range
...
```

In other words, given an input `bcb`, your if statement will look at the following indices:

(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3) `<--` The 3 in this case is your issue.

To fix your issue iterate from `[0, len(string) - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest issue is that at the top level you're just iterating on one `name,string` pair at a time, not a pair of `name,string` pairs like you want to see in your output (as shown by the paired names `a:e`).

You're trying to index the `name` and `string` values later on, but doing so is not achieving what you want (comparing two strings to each other to compute a score), since you're only accessing adjacent characters in the same string. The exception you're getting is because `i+1` may go off the end of the string. There's further confusion since you're using `i` for both the index in the inner loop and as the items taken from the outer loop (the `name, string` pairs).

To get pairs of pairs, I suggest using `itertools.combinations`:

```
import itertools

for [name1, string1], [name2, string2] in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
```

Now you can use the two name and two string variables in the rest of the loop.

I'm not entirely sure I understand how you want to compare the strings to get your score, since they're not the same length as one another. If you want to compare just the initial parts of the strings (and ignore the trailing bit of the longer one), you could use `zip` to get pairs of corresponding characters between the two strings. You can then compare them in a generator expression and add up the `bool` results (`True` is a special version of the integer `1` and `False` is a version of `0`). You can then divide by the smaller of the string's lengths (or maybe the larger if you want to penalize length differences):

```
common_letters = sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(string1, string2))
new_score = common_letters * 100 / min(len(string1), len(string2))
```

There's one more obvious issue, where you're calling `append` with two arguments. If you really want to be appending a 2-tuple, you need an extra set of parentheses:

```
similarity.append((name_seq, new_score))
```